# $stateParams params not reaching $http config object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have next function in the config step of Angular:

```
  function blockUIConfig(blockUIConfig) {
      blockUIConfig.requestFilter = function(config) {
          if ("undefined" !== typeof config.data && config.data.commActionId === CMC_ACTION_IDENTIFIER.CMC_ACTION_MONITORING) {
              return false;
          }
          return true;
      };
  }
```

The config object of the previous function corresponds to the regular $http config object: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

When I make a regular $http call everything works as expected and I have available the params data I want:

```
$http({
    url: "/pump/35801/35803", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {param1: '111'}
});
```

I can see correctly `param1` value in `config.params` map:

[image]

Now I am trying the same operation in ui-router but I cannot get it to work.

I have the next ui-router state:

```
{
state: 'pump-edit',
config: {
    url: '/pump/{equipmentId}/{pumpId}',
    params: {
        param1: null
    }
  }
}
```

And I invoke the GET call like this:

```
$state.go('pump-edit', {pumpId: vm.pump.id, equipmentId: vm.pump.equipmentId, param1: '111'}, {notify: false});
```

But in this case `config.params` doesn't exist:

[image]

If I read `equipmentId`, `pumpId` and `param1` through $stateParams in a controller I can see them without problems:

[image]

So my question is: how can I pass parameters to $http config object through ui-router?

Thank you.

Comment: $stateParams have nothing to do with $http. If you want some or all of the $stateParams to be passed as parameters when you're sending the request to your REST api, then... do it. It won't happen magically.

Comment: I imagined that. In this case I just want to have some data available in the config object when invoking one particular $state, I am not even interested in this parameter in my REST api, only in my config function. The only way I can think of is sending this parameter in the URL but i'd prefer not to do it as this is not 'real' data. Could you point another method? I cannot use $scope objects in the config step.

Comment: Navigating to a state does not involve making any http request, except, if not already done, to load the template associated to the state. If you want something to be in the config object used when sending an http request, put it there when sending the http request. I really don't understand what you want to achieve here, and why you think states and http requests are related.

Comment: When I execute the following code: `$state.go('pump-edit', {pumpId: vm.pump.id, equipmentId: vm.pump.equipmentId, param1: '111'}, {notify: false});` this is triggering a GET request because it reloads the current state and invokes some `resolve` objects I have defined in the route module. I was looking for some way to pass one parameter to not show the blockUI config screen in this case.

Comment: A GET request to what? Unless the GET request is sent to get the teplate for that state, it's not the router that sends this request. It's your applicative code. The router knows nothing about your backend, doesn't care about it, doesn't use it, and can even work fine without any backend.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my previous answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145219/discussion-between-rocotocloc-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: OK. So you are sending this request. And you should thus add the required parameters to the config when sending it. What's the concrete problem in doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JB Nizet as mentioned, $stateParams has nothing to do with $http.

The solution was adding one parameter (hideBlockUI) in my state config like this:

```
state: 'pump-edit',
        config: {
            resolve: {
               initialData: ['$stateParams', 'PumpEditService', function($stateParams, PumpEditService) {
                   return PumpEditService.getPumpData($stateParams.pumpId, $stateParams.hideBlockUI);
                }]
            },
            url: '/pump/{equipmentId}/{pumpId}',
            params: {
                hideBlockUI: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/pump/edit/pump.edit.html',
            controller: 'PumpEditController',
            controllerAs: 'vmPumpEdit',
            title: 'pump.edit.tab.title',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
              label: '{{bcPumpName}}',
              parent: 'pumps({equipmentId: bcEquipmentId})'
            }
          }
```

And then set that parameter when invoking the state:

```
$state.go('pump-edit', {pumpId: pump.id, equipmentId: $stateParams.equipmentId, hideBlockUI: true});
```

Now I invoke the $http call and set that parameter:

```
  function getPumpData(pumpId, hideBlockUI) {
      return $http.get(BASE_URL + '/rest/pump/edit/' + pumpId, {params: {hideBlockUI: hideBlockUI}})
        .then(
                function(response) {
                    return response;
                }
        );
  }
```

And finally I can get that parameter in my config function:

```
function blockUIConfig(CMC_ACTION_IDENTIFIER, blockUIConfig) {
      blockUIConfig.delay = 250;
      blockUIConfig.message = 'block.ui.default.message';
      blockUIConfig.templateUrl = 'templates/blockui-template.html';
      blockUIConfig.requestFilter = function(config) {

          console.log(config.params.hideBlockUI);
          return true;
      };
```

Thank you very much!